# Why aren't my regex captures working in mdev.conf?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, busybox, buildroot

I'm using a buildroot-built Linux image with busybox, and mdev used to manage insertion and removal of USB devices.

As a test, I tried adding the following line to my `/etc/mdev.conf` file:

```
sd([a-z])([0-9]+)   root:root 660  =drive%1%2
```

As far as I understand, the `%1` and `%2` ought to capture the parenthesized tokens matched from the regular expression and substitute those in. However this isn't what happens.

However, when I insert a USB storage device, I instead get a file *literally* named `/dev/drive%1%2` appearing among my devices, instead of say, `/dev/drivea1`.

What am I doing wrong, and could this have something to do with how Buildroot does the busybox configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable `CONFIG_FEATURE_MDEV_RENAME_REGEXP` in the busybox  configuration, which is disabled in the [default busybox configuration bundled with Buildroot](https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/busybox/busybox.config#n565).

To enable it, launch `make busybox-menuconfig` and go to `Linux System Utilities` -> `mdev` -> `Support /etc/mdev.conf` -> `Support subdirs/symlinks` -> `Support regular expressions substitutions when renaming device`.